# jQuery How to make links in a div work when the entire div is clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using this code to make entire div clickable.

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickable', function (e) {
    window.location = $(this).find('a.main').attr("href");
    return false;
});
```

There are around 4 link in the div and i want them to work as it should, So if the div is clicked the link with class `.main` gets called/clicked., I want to make it so when other links are clicked within the div .. they work as a link should.

Comment: Make a fiddle for your problem

Comment: Use `e.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 2):

Use `e.stopPropagation();` to prevent click for background clickables when you click on some `DIV`

```
$(document).on('click', 'div.clickable', function (e) {
    window.location.href = $(e.target).find('a.main').attr("href");
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

**UPDATED: check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47cHF/8/)**

Comment: Getting an error though... TypeError: e.stopPagination is not a function

Comment: mispell, use `e.stopPropagation();` not pagination !

Comment: i think your mistake was `$(this)`, I've replace it by `$(e.target)` and works fine

Comment: Now when i click on div it goes to correct link, But if i click on ANY link, it goes to {current_page_url}/undefined

Comment: I've just test it ! ARE you sure about that ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't return false, if the link itself was clicked:

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickable', function (e) {
    // only execute if no Link was clicked
    if (!$(e.currentTarget).is('a')) {
        window.location = $(this).find('a.main').attr("href");
        return false;
    }
});
```

This will execute your script only if the the DIV was clicked, not if the link was clicked. So the links inside your div will behave as usual.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickable', function (e) {
    window.location = $(this).find('a.main').attr("href");
    return false;
});

$(document).on('click', '.clickable a', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Do not propagate events from the anchors.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/3qen2/

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickable a', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).on('click', '.clickable', function (e) {
    self.location = $(this).find('a.main').attr("href");
});
```